# Solving a "loader constraint violation" error on "org.w3c.dom.Node" in an OSGi environment

Tags: java, osgi, classloader

I'm getting the following error in my OSGi environment:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/Node"
    at javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata.getStandardTree(IIOMetadata.java:716)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif.GIFImageMetadata.getAsTree(GIFImageMetadata.java:128)
    at com.xmlmind.fo.graphic.GraphicFactoryImpl.getResolution(GraphicFactoryImpl.java:184)
    at com.xmlmind.fo.graphic.GraphicFactoryImpl.createGraphic(GraphicFactoryImpl.java:145)
    at com.xmlmind.fo.graphic.GraphicFactories.createGraphic(GraphicFactories.java:128)
    at com.xmlmind.fo.converter.Converter.createGraphic(Converter.java:1943)
    at com.xmlmind.fo.converter.Converter.startExternalGraphic(Converter.java:1910)
    at com.xmlmind.fo.converter.Converter.startElement(Converter.java:635)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.xmlmind.fo.converter.Converter.convert(Converter.java:417)
```

The problem is the bundle where this call is coming from imports `org.w3c.dom.Node`

(from the "xml-apis" bundle), because this is the return type of the `getAsTree(String formatName)` method of `javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata`, while this class itself imports `org.w3c.dom.Node` from the system bundle, because it resides in the system bundle.

This leads to `org.w3c.dom.Node` being loaded by two different classloaders and hence to the above displayed loader constraint violation, when the `getAsTree` method is called.

The "xml-apis" bundle is necessary in this OSGi-environment as it provides a different version of the `org.w3c.dom` package than the system bundle (e.g. the `org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal` class can be found in the "xml-apis" bundle (and is used by other bundles in my environment), but does not exist in the system bundle).

The `javax.imageio` package is not available in a separate bundle, so I cannot "force" it to use the "xml-apis" import. 
I also tried explicitly importing version "0.0.0" (the system bundle 'version') of `org.w3c.dom` in the calling bundle , but this does not work as well, because this leads to "package uses conflicts" on other imports (which have `org.w3c.dom` as uses constraint).

I'm a bit out of ideas right now. Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this problem? Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: I had similar problems so I moved many of the xml related classes into one bundle available at https://repository.everit.biz/nexus/content/groups/public/org/everit/osgi/bundles/org.everit.osgi.bundles.org.apache.xmlcommons.full/1.4.1/.

After that I removed the javax.xml packages that are already in this bundle from the osgi boot classpath. Since that everything seems to work well.

Comment: @Balazs: Using that bundle did not solve the error unfortunately, as there were still two different classloaders trying to load org.w3c.dom.Node. Peter's answer below fixes that. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility (quite easy in fact in bnd(tools)) is to place the XML APIs bundle on the normal classpath. Assuming the new javax.xml.* are backward compatible, you will get at least one definition of these APIs. In bndtools you would add:

```
-runpath: ${repo;xml-apis__xml-apis} # assuming the bsn = xml-apis__xml-apis
```

You will also have to add the extra system packages then.

Of course the real problem is that Java does not version its packages, leaving you with this mess ...

Comment: Thanks, that works brilliantly! This case indeed makes it abundantly clear we need versioning of the packages in the JRE. Feels awkward to workaround that like this, hope that versioning will come soon!